# Unexpecting behaviour of allocating from assumed-shape array

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have always assumed that if `source` is specified in the `allocate` statement, it will copy the whole array including the respective bounds. In the following code example, I assumed that the array `x4` would have the same bounds as `x2`, namely -2 as the lower bound and 3 as the upper bound. Below, I listed the outputs of different compilers, which  to my surprise are not consistent.

```
program test
    implicit none

    real :: x(-2:3)

    print *, lbound(x), ubound(x)

    call print_bounds(x,x)

contains

    subroutine print_bounds(x1,x2)
        
        real, intent(in) :: x1(:)
        real, intent(in) :: x2(-2:)

        real, allocatable :: x3(:)
        real, allocatable :: x4(:)

        allocate(x3, source = x1)
        allocate(x4, source = x2)

        print *, lbound(x1), ubound(x1)
        print *, lbound(x2), ubound(x2)
        print *, lbound(x3), ubound(x3)
        print *, lbound(x4), ubound(x4)

    end subroutine print_bounds

end program
```

Here is the output of `gfortran 8` and `ifort`

```
          -2           3
           1           6
          -2           3
           1           6
          -2           3
```

On the other hand `gfortran 9` and `gfortran 10` leads to

```
          -2           3
           1           6
          -2           3
           1           6
           1           6
```

The section 6.7.1.2 in standard clearly states

> When an ALLOCATE statement is executed for an array with no allocate-shape-spec-list, the bounds of source-
> expr determine the bounds of the array. Subsequent changes to the bounds of source-expr do not affect the array
> bounds.

Do `gfortran 9` and `gfortran 10` violate the standard with their unexpected behavior?

Comment: You have quoted the relevant part of the standard, and shown your working for which of the two answers is "correct".  Other than a "yes", what answer are you looking for?

Comment: Although not too relevant, using Clause 6 as the source for your quote suggests you are referring to Fortan 2008 not the current Fortran 2018.

Comment: I think your interpretation of the standard is correct. I suggest filing a bug report over at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Comment: According to this online compiler, https://godbolt.org/z/qvaWao7EW  gfortran(trunk version) seems to give the expected result (but not with gcc-11). So I hope it will be fixed in gcc-12...